# Wo-Pronominaladverb und Satzbezug

Tags: pronominal-adverb

Ich habe auf [Cannoo.net](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Pronomen/PronAdv/Funktion.html) folgenden Satz gelesen:

> Du hast gewonnen, worüber sich alle freuen.

Ich denke, es soll ein Beispiel sein für ein *wo*-Wort, das sich auf einen ganzen Satz bezieht. Hier freuen sich die Leute also über den Fakt, dass *du* gewonnen hat.
Allerdings klingt der Satz in dieser Lesart für mich etwas komisch. Nicht wirklich falsch, aber nach Abituraufsatz, in dem auf Krampf versucht wird, kompliziert zu schreiben (zu viele *welche*-Referenzen und so).

Dann fiel mir schließlich auf, dass es eine zweite Lesart gibt, und die fühlt sich komplett richtig und elegant an – in der Langform:

> Du hast das gewonnen, worüber sich alle freuen (zum Beispiel den Pokal).

Der *worüber*-Satz bezieht sich also jetzt allein auf *das* und definiert es. Jetzt meine Fragen:

- Welche Lesart ist die natürlichere?
- Kommt die erste Version (worüber bezieht sich auf den Fakt) nur mir so rumpelig vor?
- Gibt es Beispiele für einen Satzbezug, die **keine** andere Lesart zulassen?

Comment: Wenn sich die Leute über den Sieg an sich freuen, dann könnte man den zweiten Satz zu "Du hast das Spiel gewonnen, worüber sich alle freuen." erweitern, was mMn nicht besser ist als die erste Variante.

Comment: Wenn du aber "das, worüber sich alle freuen" gewonnen hast, dann hat das doch nichts mehr mit dem ersten Satz zu tun, oder? (Außer man liest auch den ersten Satz so, was eig. auch grammatikalisch vertretbarer ist.)

Comment: @Carlster... doch, ich geb dir mal ein anderes Beispiel... "Du hast gefragt, was ich nicht zu denken wagte". Der zweite Teil kann sich auf den Fakt des Fragens an sich beziehen, oder auf das, was gefragt wird... wobei ich auch hier zweiteres viel viel besser finde

Comment: Dieser Satz hat meinem Verständnis nach eine einzige Lesart, nämlich diejenige, wo sich der Nebensatz auf das Gefragte bezieht. Egal, ob man jetzt im Hauptsatz ein "das" einfügt oder nicht.

Comment: Was bei dir die "erste Leseart" ist, ist für mich die "zweite". Wollte ich dies ausdrücken, würde ich sagen "Du hast gewonnen und darüber freuen sich alle". Bei deiner zweiten (und meiner primären) Leseart muss ich aber zugeben, dass ich den Satz inhaltlich unvollständig finde. Es gibt da nämlich auch nochmals zwei Intepretationen: Dein Pokal-Beispiel (**Du** hast es gewonnen und alle freuen sich über **es**) und "Du hast das gewonnen, worüber sich alle freuen würden, wenn sie es denn selbst gewonnen hätten."

Comment: Mit "erste Variante" habe ich den Satz von canoo.net gemeint, nicht die Lesart.

Comment: @Em1: Die zweite Variante der zweiten Variante (»Du hast das gewonnen, worüber sich alle freuen würden, wenn sie es denn selbst gewonnen hätten.«) läse ich da nur, wenn da auch ein Irrealis stünde, also »Du hast gewonnen, worüber sich alle freuen würden.«.

Comment: Wäre "Du hast geschrien, worüber alle entsetzt waren." eine gleichwertige Konstruktion?

Comment: @Carlster Ja, kann auch zweideutig verstanden werden. Wobei ich denke, hier eine deutlichere Tendenz zu "Es waren alle entsetzt, dass du geschrien hast" ist als zu "Du hast wegen geanu dem geschrien, wegen wessen alle entsetzt waren". Puh, selbst der Satz ist nicht eindeutig. :)

Comment: Es wäre schön, wenn es eine Möglichkeit gäbe, die Häufigkeit solcher Konstruktionen zu recherchieren - ich persönlich würde nie zu einer solchen greifen, eher zu den Varianten 3 und 4 aus Wrzlprmfts Liste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Die erste Lesart ist meiner Meinung nach die natürlichere, zumindest in diesem Fall, hundertpro wäre aber bei noch ambigeren Sätzen auch das anders. Beispiel:

> Du liest, was alle in der Zeitung lesen. 
>   
>   Hier ist die natürlichste Lesart wohl, dass der Angesprochene liest, was alle anderen in der Zeitung auch lesen. Könnte aber auch unter Verbiegungen bedeuten, dass alle in der Zeitung lesen, was der Angesprochene liest. Die Frage gehört also vielleicht eher in die Semantik als in die Grammatik/Syntax.

- Die erste Version ist rumpelig, weil jeder Sprecher einfach zwei Sätze machen würde oder die natürlichere Variante wählen würde:

  > Wir freuen uns darüber, dass du gewonnen hast.
- Klar gibt es solche Sätze, die nicht ambig sind, wenn zum Beispiel (wiederum semantisch) sich der erste Satzteil nicht auf den zweiten beziehen lässt:

  > Du bist grün, worüber wir uns freuen.

Comment: Beachte, dass »Wir freuen uns darüber, dass du gewonnen hast.« nicht äquivalent zum Beispielsatz ist. Jener enthält »du hast gewonnen« als neue, zentrale Information, während sie in diesem schon als bekannt vorausgesetzt wird oder nebensächlich ist.

Comment: sehr schöne Antwort... die hilft mir extrem weiter

Answer (score 5):

Der Reihe nach:

**Welche Lesart ist die natürlichere?**

Die erste. Die zweite ist zwar grammatikalisch denkbar, funktioniert aber nur mit spezieller Betonung in gesprochener Sprache – wenn überhaupt.

**Kommt die erste Version nur mir so rumpelig vor?**

Der Satz kommt mir auch unnatürlich vor, was aber weniger an der Grammatik als am Inhalt liegt. Ein hoffentlich natürlicheres Beispiel:

> Meine Schwiegermutter besuchte uns, worüber ich mich sehr ärgerte.

Außerdem würde ich diese Konstruktion nur nutzen, wenn beide Teilsätze sehr kurz sind und ich so eine Parataxe vermeiden kann; ansonsten würde ich die Teilsätze zu eigenen Sätzen machen oder durch *und* verbinden und den zweiten mit *darüber* einleiten (siehe unten).

**<s>Gibt es Beispiele für einen Satzbezug, die KEINE andere Lesart zulassen?</s>

Wie kann man den Beispielsatz abändern, sodass er eindeutig ist?**

Diverse:

> Du hast gewonnen – worüber sich alle freuen.
>
> Du hast gewonnen. Darüber freuen sich alle.
>
> Du hast gewonnen und darüber freuen sich alle.
>
> Du hast gewonnen; eine Tatsache, über die sich alle freuen.

Comment: "Welche Lesart ist die natürlichere? -> Die erste" Strongly disagree. Als ich den Satz las, dachte ich spontan an die 'zweite' und bin erst durch Emanuels Erklärungen auf die andere gekommen. Das liegt aber tatsächlich am Beispiel. Dein Beispiel lässt die andere Interpretation gar nicht zu.

Comment: @Em1 Naja, es geht ja auch nur um Beispeile, wo sich "worüber" auf den ganzen Satz bezieht.

Comment: Den Hinweis auf den Irrealis in Deinem Kommentar zur Frage halte ich für einen zentralen Punkt. So gesehen ist die Fassung "Du hast [sc. dasjenige] gewonnen, worüber sich alle freuen [sc. würden, hätten sie es denn]" eine elliptische Konstruktion. Versteht man das canoo-Beispiel in diesem Sinne, dann setzt man eine doppelte Ellipse voraus - weggelassen werden "das(jenige)" und "würden". Das ist dann m.E. keine Frage der Grammatik mehr.

Comment: Sehr schönes Beispiel, das mit der Oma... das meinte ich eigentlich mit "Beispiele ohne andere Lesart"...  die Punktierungsspiele kannst du meiner Ansicht nach wieder rausnehmen, da man hier sehr viel diskutieren kann... was die Betonung angeht, das sehe ich anders. Man muss beide Lesarten verschieden betonen, aber nicht die eine garnicht und die andere voll ungewöhnlich

Comment: @Emanuel: Wieso kann man über die Alternativen mit anderer Zeichensetzung viel diskutieren? Sie leisten doch das Gewünschte, halt nur in geschriebener Sprache.

Comment: Ich finde das Semikolon an sich ein ziemlich überflüssiges Satzzeichen und kann damit nix anfangen, wüsste auch nicht, wie ich vorlesen soll, wenn ich eins sehe. Aber das sei mal dahingestellt... ich finde im wesentlichen Beispiel 1 fragwürdig. Seit wann trennt man Nachgedanken mittels Semikolon ab? Das macht der Bindestrich schon ganz gut. Aber auch das sei dahingestellt.. ich wollte Beispiele mit "worüber" die nur einen Satzbezug haben können. Der letzte Teil deiner Antwort geht also an meiner Frage vorbei. Könntest du da die Überschrift ändern zu "eindeutige Möglichkeiten der Punktierung"?

Comment: @Emanuel: Gedankenstriche (Bindestriche sind etwas anderes) und Semikola sind häufig austauschbar, aber nicht immer. Das Semikolon kann auch Nachgedanken abgrenzen, zumindest tut es das in vielen Beispielen zu § 80 (1) der Rechtschreibregeln. Allerdings ist mir aufgefallen, dass wir hier keinen nebengeordneten Teilsatz, sondern einen Nebensatz haben, sodass die Variante nicht rechtschreibkonform ist (aber wohl immer noch zielführend, was das Vermeiden von Ungenauigkeiten betrifft).

Comment: @Emanuel: Nebenbei: Das deutsche Wort für *punctuation* ist *Zeichensetzung* und nicht *Punktierung.*